# Excel - 2 tables in 2 worksheets (Find cell value in Table 2 if 2 cells from 2 tables match)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Here's a simple explanation of my current dilemma:

Table 1 (worksheet1):
**Column A** contains *Call Description* (each call description has 3 time rates)
**Column B** contains *Time Rate* (day, evening and weekend)

Table 2 (worksheet2):
Similar layout where **Column A and B** contains *Call Description* and *Time Rate* but **Column H** contains the cost of that specific combination of *Call Description* and *Time Rate*.

So, I want to find out the cost of a specific call combination (**Column H** in Table 2) when the *Call Description* and *Time Rate* matches in both tables. Thus returning the cost value in a **Column T** in worksheet 1.

Essentially I'd want **Column T** in worksheet 1 to return the cost of the call combination.

Thanks

Is using Index and Match the right way to go?

Comment: The call description and time rate columns are similar in both tables, but column H in table 2 contains some information which lets you calculate some value for column T? If call description and time rate are similar, why do you need to pull extra information from table 2? Do you want it to be similar to column H?

Comment: It can be, just depends on your approach. Match can be used for merged data (smashing the strings together) like `Match(Desc&TimeRate,A1:A3&B1:B3,0)` or you can build the array of row numbers using nested if's and feed that to the `INDEX()` or produce a logical like `(A1:A3 = Desc)*(B1:B3 = TimeRate)*Row(A1:A3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array formula `INDEX(MATCH())`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!H:H,MATCH(Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

You'll have to apply it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.